# Mixed precision arithmetic: Algorithm for big float division with big integer mantissa?

Tags: javascript, precision, biginteger, bigdecimal, arbitrary-precision

I have written a Big Integer class that works well. I want to write a Big Decimal class. I've structure the class as a float with a base 10 exponent--i.e. in the form of M*10^e where 10^0 implies the number lies between [0.1, 1).

Here, M is a BigInteger and the 10^e is used to determined where the decimal is. I want to divide such numbers. When the quotient is greater than 1, I can do integer division to determine where the decimal point should be. When the numerator is greater than the denominator in magnitude, the result of integer division is less than one. How can I know where the decimal should be?

Note that to perform the division without loss of precision, I multiply the numerator by a large power of 10, such as 10^24, before dividing.

I have tried differencing the exponents (e.g. 10^(e1 - e2)). This produces the correct answer most of the time, but sometimes the exponent is off by one. This can also occur when the numerator is large than the denominator.

To illustrate the issue:
72*10^2 / 35*10^2 = ~2.06 BUT differencing the exponents would give me ~0.206.

Notes: I understand base 2 would be better for the exponent term, and my BigInteger class uses base 2 numbers, but I don't know how to determine where the decimal should go with base 2 either. Also, the class is written in AssemblyScript, which has similar syntax to TypeScript, which is similar to JavaScript. I cannot use external packages.

Full imlementation: https://github.com/Web3-API/as-bigint/blob/main/assembly/BigFloat.ts

Division function:

```
  div(other: BigFloat, minPrecision: i32 = this.minPrecision): BigFloat {
    let dividend = this.mantissa;
    let divisor = other.mantissa;
    // divide with padding to maintain precision
    let dividendLength = dividend.toString().length - (dividend.isNegative ? 1 : 0);
    let divisorLength = divisor.toString().length - (divisor.isNegative ? 1 : 0);
    const lengthDiff = dividendLength - divisorLength;
    const padding = minPrecision - (lengthDiff < 0 ? lengthDiff : 0);
    dividend = BigFloat.mulBigIntPowTen(dividend, padding);
    const mantissa: BigInt = dividend.div(divisor);
    // calculate exponent
    let exponent: i32;
    const gteZero: boolean = this.mantissa.magCompareTo(other.mantissa) >= 0;
    if (gteZero) {
      const naiveDiv: BigInt = this.mantissa.div(other.mantissa);
      const naiveDivLen: i32 = naiveDiv.toString().length;
      exponent = naiveDiv.isNegative ? naiveDivLen - 1 : naiveDivLen;
    } else {
      exponent = this.e - other.e;
    }
    return new BigFloat(mantissa, exponent, this.minPrecision);
  }
```

test cases (look at "constructs from fraction" section): https://github.com/Web3-API/as-bigint/blob/main/assembly/__tests__/BigFloat_read_write.spec.ts

This test case fails due to off-by-one error with decimal placement:

```
numerator = BigInt.fromString("23627");
denominator = BigInt.fromString("1093746923469083704986");
bigFloat = BigFloat.fromFraction(numerator, denominator, 30);
expect(bigFloat.toString(30)).toStrictEqual("0.000000000000000021601889333833");
```

Comment: can you share your concrete implementation with testcases?

Comment: added links and example to post

Comment: "*in the form of M*10^e where 10^0 implies the number lies between [0.1, 1).*" - that doesn't quite work out if `M` is a Big*Integer*.

Comment: It does work. A number like 23.45 is represented as 0.2345 * 10^2 by storing the integer 2345 and the exponent value of 2. The decimal position in 0.2345 is implied, and is adjusted by the exponential term when necessary. This is very similar to how standard floats are stored: https://www.rfwireless-world.com/Tutorials/floating-point-tutorial.html#:~:text=IEEE%20754%20standard%20floating%20point%20Division%20Algorithm%20Division,E1%29%20%2F%20%28-1%29%20S2%20%28M2%20x%202%20E2%29